# xfs_growfs: is not a mounted XFS filesystem

Tags: linux, redhat, centos7

I am trying to increase the logic volume of my partition disk.Partition table got updated and all went well. To resize the file system, I ran the below command as I am on RedHat.

```
xfs_growfs  /dev/vg_osdisk/lv_swap
```

It returns the error as below.

```
[root@HA---------S ~]# xfs_growfs  /dev/vg_osdisk/lv_swap
xfs_growfs: /dev/vg_osdisk/lv_swap is not a mounted XFS file system
```

I have tried to run the below command to check the type of file system. Here it shows XFS only.

```
 [root@HA---------S ~]# df -Th
Filesystem                    Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_osdisk-lv_root xfs        72G  5.9G   66G   9% /
```

But I can see my 200G space as below.

```
[root@------------S ~]# lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                     2:0    1     4K  0 disk
sda                     8:0    0   300G  0 disk
├─sda1                  8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot
├─sda2                  8:2    0    99G  0 part
│ ├─vg_osdisk-lv_root 253:0    0  71.2G  0 lvm  /
│ ├─vg_osdisk-lv_swap 253:1    0 207.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
│ └─vg_osdisk-lv_home 253:2    0    20G  0 lvm  /home
└─sda3                  8:3    0   200G  0 part
  └─vg_osdisk-lv_swap 253:1    0 207.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

So how can I increase the space of the new logic system to the existing partition disk.

Comment: `lv_swap` sounds like a swap partition. swap partitions don't have a file system.

Comment: I think you resized the wrong logical volume. 200GB [swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yeah man.. Now i realized that i resized the wrong volume. Instead of /dev/vg_osdisk/lv_root, I resized the /dev/vg_osdisk/lv_swap volume. So how can I rollback from this..

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks for pointing me in  a right direction..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/dev/vg_osdisk/lv_swap` is a part of swap area (as used already logical volume) and cannot be expand xfs_growfs command.

The sda3 (207.9G) partition is already assigned as a part of swap area.

If you want to increase OS filesystem area, you must decrease swap area(reduce swap logical volume) with `swapoff` command, and extend lv_root or lv_home logical volume and then extend xfs filesystem `xfs_growfs /dev/v_osdisk/lv_root` or `xfs_growfs /dev/v_osdisk/lv_home`.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy.. By mistake, i have extended the wrong partition... Your solution helped a lot.. Thank you once again..

Answer (score 0):

eg; Increasing size of the home directory in RedHat 8.

If you run the below command error will occur,

[root@PG-SwitchApp-Serv ~]# xfs_growfs -r /dev/mapper/rootvg-homelv
xfs_growfs: /dev/mapper/rootvg-homelv is not a mounted XFS filesystem

Solu: Run command :

[root@PG-SwitchApp-Serv ~]# xfs_growfs /home/

meta-data=/dev/mapper/rootvg-homelv isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=65536 blks
=                       sectsz=4096  attr=2, projid32bit=1
=                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=1, rmapbt=0
=                       reflink=1
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=262144, imaxpct=25
=                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
=                       sectsz=4096  sunit=1 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data blocks changed from 262144 to 13369344

--
KG